How to pass installation error to "Error URL" in a clickonce installation?
If the clickonce installation finds an error during installation, it provides an error message that says click 'here' do view possible solutions for the error and it connects to my support URL. I would like for the error message to be sent to a field in the target page of the URL. Multiple Tabs are opened on the browser when responding to the error message from the installation, when you click the "Error URL" link.
This is for installation errors for a clickonce application.
I expected the support URL to be opened and it does, but error message is not provided.
